# Removing lead zeroes from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I seem to be having issues removing leading zeroes from an array that is created by the user. For example, the program I am writing will ask the user to input a mathematical expression (input received as a string):

Eg : 1234 + 1234

Before going into creating a function to solve this problem, I can't seem to get my array to ignore the leading zeroes. This is because I am switching the user input from string to integer and then positioning these values at the end of the array (constant size is 20). Below is how I convert from string to an integer array.

```
void stringToInt(int arr[], string value1, int SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
         if (arr[i] < 0)
             arr[i] = 0;
         arr[SIZE - 1 - i] = value1[value1.length() - 1 - i] - 48;
}
```

This is how I tried to remove zeroes:

```
void removeLeadZeroes(int arr[], string value1, int SIZE){
    bool print = true;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++){
        if (arr[i] == 0
            print = false;
        if (print)
            cout << arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way for converting strings to integers. There is a buildin function called `atoi()` in C++. You will have to use `stdlib.h` header file for this. Converting character array to integer using this function will automatically remove unwanted values in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //The character array
    char a[3];

    //The integer variable
    int b;
    gets(a);

    //Converts to integer
    b=atoi(a);

    //To prove that value is an integer and 
    //mathematical operations can be done on it
    cout<<b+2;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helped. Ask if you need any help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you found the solution.

Comment: I assume this is for a class assignment - you should probably check the contents of the array for any undesired content.
You should probably use strtol, which doesn't result in undefined behaviour on converting non-integer values.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: There is no function called `gets` in the C and C++ languages. It was flagged obsolete 18 years ago and was removed 6 years ago.

Comment: There is `gets` function under the stdlib library. By the way there are new methods to do the same.

Comment: it is a class project i am working on but since i have an exam coming up ill be putting this on hold until this weekend but ill def see if it works for me thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach using C. `arr2` contains the array without leading zeros. `48` being the ASCII value for `0` can be used to check for zeros in the given array. However I recommend to use built-in `atoi` as suggested by @Ronald.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

        const char *arr1 = "01234+123";
        char *arr2 = (char *)malloc(20);
        int i,j=0;

        for(i=0; arr1[i] != '\0'; i++){
                if((arr1[i] - 48) != 0){
                        arr2[++j] = arr1[i];
                }
        }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: thank you for your input ill definitely be trying this over the weekened thank you very much!